# Exclude entire interface based on inner property

Tags: typescript

I'm developing a frontend application and our backend generates an SDK that the frontend can use for typings/service calls/etc. One of the main objects that the frontend uses is causing me a few headaches in regards to proper typings. Here are very simplified example types generated by the SDK...

```
export enum ModelTypes {
  ModelOne = 'ModelOne',
  ModelTwo = 'ModelTwo'
}

export interface ModelOne {
  score: ModelOneScores;
  metadata: ModelOneMetadata;
  modelOneProp_A: string;
  modelOneProp_B: string;
}

export interface ModelTwo {
  modelTwoProp_A: number;
  modelTwoProp_B: number;
}

export interface Model {
  id: string;
  created: Date;
  updated: Date;
  data: (ModelOne | ModelTwo);
  type: ModelTypes;
}
```

As you can see, `ModelOne` has the "score" and "metadata" properties, while `ModelTwo` does not. I have a function to retrieve a score from any "Model" like so (you can assume that inside `ModelOneScores` or any other `ModelNScores` interface is an "averageScore" property):

```
export function getModelScore(model: Sdk.Model): number {
  switch (model.type) {
    case Sdk.ModelTypes.ModelOne:
      return model.data.score.averageScore;
  }
}
```

Obviously, TypeScript complains because `score` doesn't exist on `ModelTwo`. What is a type I can use to tell TypeScript "I will never pass a `ModelTwo` to this function so `score` will always be available on `Sdk.Model`"?

*Note:* there are more Models than just `ModelTwo` that don't have `score`, so preferably a catch-all type to exclude *any* `models` without the `score` property would be a nice-to-have.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wg8zbN) work for you? If yes, I'll write answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, sorry about that.

Comment: @wonderflame I can't change any code for these `model` interfaces, it's auto-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a type for these `Model` instances that will always have `ModelOne` for `data` instead of `ModelTwo`:

```typescript
export type ModelWithModelOne = Exclude<Model, "data"> & {data: ModelOne};
```

The `Exclude` there isn't strictly necessary (I kind of like it for clarity of intent), you could just do:

```typescript
export type ModelWithModelOne = Exclude<Model, "data"> & {data: ModelOne};
```

Either way, then you'd use that in the function parameter.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEFQBwGwQwMYFMAWB7GATJAnUBJUOTbTALgCgkAPKNHAF1AEsA7B3AM0SVAFk02GAHlWSAMoJ6SAM6gA3hVDKiAN1xwA5hKk4kZUKwCuAWwBGuANwUAvhQogIrNAxS5o8ZOizvCxUpQ0dIws7Fw8-IJIImJ8SAzEcAkKSioyaCbxKGyaBjIMODnWdlS09ExIxiaRQgAqAJ5QsikqNdGivAC8oABEAkIdPQA0qcr90bUA7mig3X1RMFNow7b2QeWhHDjcyG0xvIqtMrr6ex2S0jLWrZkJmElwBuP7cXcP1yomCx0ACjhoUAA+uA8gUiqNQF8BmI-gDAQAhUGFViaYprMohNhbHa8Z5LFqfBZLWFAkGGUwWHAfZRQibTEkIgxVSlo0rBJhY8K7Z4E5TMcigfLI1EQhB6JJIAUAEQl1NARig9w40tlEKVjzOYlAAB89ks5QxGqc8Uarqt1iFDU09gB1ZiuZ4dWagACi1AQMCM2AAPM8hr11T0AHygABkCnVT2+Yhs1jZG04RlYCAYzDQrFA2gYzwuegAFLSYAZgAAqcSYADWADoS8BnnaHdGkABKJkU9yHNKTe0IFCgAsLKtWlu81qgBBwGS8Uvl6u1k1NGRVx1iShj9egPQMIw4DOFqvqqvHaRVuDqHBaHTSOV2VpbncZgAMaKAA)

If this is completely a one-off, you could just do that with the parameter's type directly (here I've left out `Exclude`):

```typescript
export function getModelScore(model: Sdk.Model & {data: ModelOne}): number {
    // ...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEFQBwGwQwMYFMAWB7GATJAnUBJUOTbTALgCgkAPKNHAF1AEsA7B3AM0SVAFk02GAHlWSAMoJ6SAM6gA3hVDKiAN1xwA5hKk4kZUKwCuAWwBGuANwUAvhQogIrNAxS5o8ZOizvCxUpQ0dIws7Fw8-IJIImJ8SAzEcAkKSioyaCbxKGyaBjIMODnWdlS09ExIxiaRQgAqAJ5QsikqNdGivAC8oABEAkIdPQA0qcr90bUA7mig3X1RMFNow7b2QeWhHDjcyG0xvIqtMrr6ex2S0jLWrZkJmElwBuP7cXcP1yomCx0ACjhoUAA+uA8gUiqNQF8BmI-gDAQAhUGFViaYprMohNhbHa8Z5LFqfBZLWFAkGGUwWHAfZRQibTEkIgxVSlo0rBJhY8K7Z4E5TMcigfLI1EQhB6JJIAUAEQl1NARig9w40tlEKVjzOYlAAB89ks5QxGqc8Uarqs2RtOEZWAgGMw0KxQNoGM8LnoABS0mAGYAAKnEmAA1gA6X3AHkAMgU6qe3zENgAlEyKe5DmlJswGAgUKBPQtg4amgnea1QAg4DJeH6AyGwyamjJg88OpRS23QHoGEYcI6vcH1cHjtJg3B1DgtDppHK7K1O93HQAGNFAA)

Comment: Is there a shorthand for something like `{ data: AnyModelWithScoreProperty }`? I ask only because I would need to list out every model... so it would be `Exclude<Model, 'data'> & { data: ModelOne } | { data: ModelThree } | { data: ModelFive }` (assuming `ModelThree` and `ModelFive` both have the `score` property of course).

Comment: I did mark this as accepted since it does solve my issue, though. Thanks!

Comment: @exk0730 - Yes, if I'm reading right you could do `& { data: { score: { averageScore: number } } }`. The key to that is that Typescript's type system is *structural* (based on the shape of types), not *nominal* (based on the names/identities of types). So what we're doing there is staying that the function can only accept something that is shaped like the intersection of a `Model` and an object with a `data` property which is an object with a `score` property which is `{ averageScore: number }`. And since that's all that you're allowed to pass in, the type of `model.data.score` is known.